# Website for finding archived .desktop launchers?

Tags: launcher, websites

As many of you can relate, updates to 12.04 took away certain launchers from the dash menu.

Some of which that I used constantly were "Shut Down", "Restart", "Log Off", and "Software Sources".

Now, I know I can use the HUD to Shut Down, Restart, and Log Off, and I can run `software-properties-gtk` to access Sources.

But, is there anywhere I can look to find archived .desktop files for these launchers?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can use the HUD to shut down and restart now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are mine, if it helps..

**/usr/share/applications/indicator-session-shutdown.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shut Down
TryExec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown
Icon=system-shutdown
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session
```

**/usr/share/applications/indicator-session-restart.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Restart
TryExec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --restart
Icon=system-restart
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session
```

**/usr/share/applications/indicator-session-logout.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Log Out
TryExec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --logout
Icon=system-log-out
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session
```

**/usr/share/applications/software-properties-gtk.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Software Sources
GenericName=Software Sources
Comment=Configure the sources for installable software and updates
Exec=software-properties-gtk
Icon=software-properties
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;
MimeType=text/x-apt-sources-list;
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-properties
X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=software
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for sharing the info with me. :)